# Multiplying by a percentage not working as intended

Tags: sql, having, multiplication

My problem is I am trying to list staff members whose salary is less than or equal to the average salary, which is increased by 50%, but also greater than or equal to average salary decreased by 50%. Been trying to work this out, I've got no errors, but for some reason, it's not displaying what I'm meant to be displaying.

```
SELECT staffNo, salary
FROM Staff
GROUP BY staffNo
HAVING salary <= AVG(salary * 0.5) OR salary >= AVG(salary / 0.5)
ORDER BY salary ASC;
```

This now prints:

[image: 1]

Instead of what's required:

[image: 1]

If anything else is required, I'll provide it, but any help would be appreciate, thanks!

Edit:

```
SELECT staffNo, salary
FROM Staff
GROUP BY staffNo
HAVING salary <= AVG(salary * 0.5) AND salary >= AVG(salary / 0.5)
ORDER BY salary ASC;
```

Comment: Is it the ordering you require to be fixed? Cause I don't see anything else that's wrong technically

Comment: @davejal I've deleted it, changed it to staffNo, doesn't remove the 30,000 value

Comment: At this point I think you should start debugging and rethinking the data you think you have

Comment: @davejal I've tweaked it a little bit and now I'm receiving null values

Comment: could you post your raw data? now I'm working with the result and I'm not sure if it's correct or not (eventhough you think it's not correct, the query thinks it)

Comment: the edited version requires the salary to be both bigger and smaller at the same time. It will only provide 1 result and that would be equal to (because you have that in both where clauses

Answer (score 1):

I think one of your problems here is the math.

`salary * 0.5` is *half* the salary, and  `salary / 0.5` is *double* the salary!

So by your specification you're after `HAVING salary BETWEEN AVG(salary) * 1.5 AND AVG(salary) * 0.5`.

I'm not 100% sure, but using `AVG(salary)` instead of having the operation inside the `AVG()` parameters would allow for the engine to optimize them to a single operation.

Comment: I didn't even see that. I think that nailed it.

Comment: Yeah, I always avoid division because it can get confusing like that... OP could also take a look at the concepts of [quartiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile) and percentiles, since they might be what he is really after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see what differences there are between the two queries

```
SELECT staffNo, salary, 'lessthen' type
FROM Staff
GROUP BY staffNo
HAVING salary <= AVG(salary * 0.5)
ORDER BY salary ASC
union
SELECT staffNo, salary, 'morethen' type
FROM Staff
GROUP BY staffNo
HAVING salary >= AVG(salary / 0.5)
ORDER BY salary ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT staffNo, salary
FROM Staff
GROUP BY staffNo
HAVING salary <= AVG(salary) * 1.5 OR salary >= AVG(salary) / 2.0
ORDER BY salary ASC;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!
http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/308249